# WebMethod expand result object

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, webmethod

I have an asmx web service being consumed by excisting clients. The clients have imported the service as Service References in Visual Studio.

Now I need to change the Response-object `GetUnitDescription_Request` to have som extra properties for *new* clients, but the excisting ones shall still work.

```
Public Class GetUnits_Result
    property Id()
    property Name() 'This and some more is new!
    property Timestamp()
End Class
```

Now, when I deploy this service and overriding the old one, the clients get the `Id` right, but `Timestamp` gets a default value - probably because it fails with the new Name? I would just like the service to say "hey, just bypass this new `Name()`-property and go on".
I do not have control over the clients, so I can't update the service reference.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True, Description:="Gets Units"), SoapHeader("sHeader")> _
Public Function GetUnits(ByVal req As GetUnits_Request) As GetUnits_Result
    return GetUnits(req)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create a new `WebMethod` to return a new response object with the new properties. It should be able to reuse most of the same business logic.

This way, the old clients will get what they expect, and so will the new clients.

Comment: I could do that - but I thought there would be a better way where I don't need to maintain two - and by time more - almost similar methods.